# CasperJS doesn't update page after click

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I've ran in to a problem after updating casperJS to the newest version.

```
this.clickLabel('Add a link...', 'span');
    this.sendKeys('input[id="newLinkSourceUrl"]', "http://google.com", {keepFocus: true, reset: true});
    this.clickLabel('Shrink', 'span');

    this.wait(30000, function() {
          this.capture('n1.png');
    });
```

This used to work just fine, but now after clicking "Shrink", the page doesn't update even after waiting very long. I'm attaching the result I get.
[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnaZO.png)

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: I'm currently using 2.1.1 PhantomJS version. I have just registered these events and you were right, there is a resource error. 
ResourceError: {
 "errorCode": 5,
 "errorString": "Operation cancelled",
 "id": 168,
 "status": null,
 "statusText": null,
 "url": "http://hootsuite.com/ajax/scheduler/shorten-url"
}

Comment: You can try to run it with `casperjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true script.js`

Comment: Sadly but it returns the exact same result. I'm using the latest versions of phantomjs and casperjs, maybe I should try to downgrade one of them?

Comment: That's almost certainly a PhantomJS problem, but I doubt that downgrading would solve it. You can try 1.9.8, 1.9.7 and 2.0.1/2.0.0 in that order.

Comment: CasperJS is not compatible with the latest version of PhantomJS

There is a workaround - you have to edit the bootstrap.js file in casperjs bin folder.  Here is a gist of how the new file should look like:

https://gist.github.com/jakblak/e02b11b7336fb82ac4b5